# Adding Dropdowns in a vue.js router-link

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-router

I have created a vue.js router and inserting the links found in an array using the  structure found hereafter. This displays the links horizontally. However, I would like to insert dropdowns, instead of simple links. Can this be done using this or similar structure somehow?

```
<nav style="text-align: right">
  <router-link class="spacing" v-for="routes in links"
  v-bind:key="routes.id"
  :to="`${routes.page}`">{{routes.text}}</router-link>
</nav>

      links: [
    {
      id: 0,
      text: 'Buy',
      page: '/Buy'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Sale',
      page: '/Sale'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Transactions',
      page: '/Transactions'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: 'Help',
      page: '/Help'
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, there are a few ways you could do that, though you'll have to loop over something different than the `<router-link>`, since that component renders an `<a>` tag.

I would first adjust your HTML to allow for the drop-down interaction you want, whether it's hover- or click-based, then change your data structure and loop to support it.

I might do something like this:

```html
<nav style="text-align: right">

  <div
    class="nav-item"
    v-for="link in links" // Move loop to container of shown link and it's dropdown markup
  >
    <router-link
      :key="link.id"
      :to="`${link.page}`"
    >
      {{ link.text }}
    </router-link>

    <div class="nav-item-drawer">
      <router-link
        v-for="subLink in link.subLinks"
        :key="subLink.id"
        :to="`${subLink.page}`"
      >
        {{ subLink.text }}
      </router-link>
    </div>

  </div>

</nav>
```

with the following data structure:

```js
  links: [
    {
      id: 0,
      text: 'Buy',
      page: '/Buy',
      subLinks: [
        {
          id: 0,
          text: 'Buy Sublink 1',
          page: '/Buy-more'
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          text: 'Buy Sublink 2',
          page: '/Buy-less'
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Sale',
      page: '/Sale'
    },
    //...
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer Joe. You mentioned that "you'll have to loop over something different than the <router-link>". What would you suggest?

Comment: @JF0001 Just a container element, such as a `<div>`, then have the `<router-link>` component inside that container. I tried to do something like that in the example I gave